# Multiline input in Bash with subshell term inside single quotes

Tags: bash, escaping

I would like to use approx. the following construct in Bash for generating lines in a configuration file for PostgreSQL:

```
T0=$(date +%s)
cat > $PGDATA/recovery.conf <<EOL
recovery_target_inclusive = true
recovery_target_time = \'$(date -d @$T0 "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")\'
recovery_target_timeline = latest
EOL
```

I currently receive this output:

```
recovery_target_inclusive = true
recovery_target_time = \'2018-01-04 12:47:44 UTC\'
recovery_target_timeline = latest
```

How can I obtain a version that does not escape the single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: don't escape the quotes.

```
cat > $PGDATA/recovery.conf <<EOL
recovery_target_inclusive = true
recovery_target_time = '$(date -d @$T0 "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")'
recovery_target_timeline = latest
EOL
```